# How do I upload files to a specific folder in Django?

Tags: python, django

After the user uploads 2 .ini files, I would like it to save both files inside the following folder.

MEDIA/uploadedconfigs/Printer/Plastic/

However, it's currently saving to the address below.

MEDIA/uploadedconfigs/None/

Below is the code that uploads the files. 
models.py

```
def UploadedConfigPath(instance, filename):

    return os.path.join('uploadedconfigs', str(instance.id), filename)

class ConfigFiles(models.Model):

    Printer = models.CharField(_('Printer Model'),
    max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, unique=False)
    Plastic = models.CharField(_('Plastic'),    
    max_length=40, blank=True, null=True, unique=False)
    creator = models.CharField(_('Creator'),
    max_length=40, blank=True, null=True, unique=False)
    HDConfig = models.FileField(_('High Detail'), 
    upload_to=UploadedConfigPath)
    LDConfig = models.FileField(_('Low Detail'), 
    upload_to=UploadedConfigPath)

    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(_('date_joined'), 
    default=timezone.now)
```

I'm not what "instance" is doing, but I was told it's what is spitting out the "None" folder name.  I was also told I may need to place the files in a temporary folder but I'm not sure what that would entail. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the function `UploadedConfigPath` with this :

```
def UploadedConfigPath(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('uploadedconfigs', 'Printer', 'Plastic', filename)
```

**Edit :**

This should do it :

```
def UploadedConfigPath(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('uploadedconfigs', instance.Printer, instance.Plastic, filename)
```

Comment: I may not have been clear. I'm trying to upload to the variables 'Printer' and 'Plastic' that the user inputs, as shown in the ModelClass. Using your method would upload to folders actually called 'Printer', not the user input variables.

Comment: @RknRobin yes, you haven't been really clear at all... Anyway I've edited my answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

try to use original approach by setting parameter in settings.py

```
 MEDIA_ROOT = join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../media/')"
 MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In your file:

```
def UploadedConfigPath(instance, filename):
       return os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'uploadedconfigs/', str(instance.id), '/', filename)
```

Comment: I may have simplified this too much but I am using that approach, and wrapped it all up into the variable MEDIA shown above. My settings looks like what is shown above, and uploads to the MEDIA_ROOT correctly (without needing settings.MEDIA_ROOT). My issue is the (str(instance.id), filename) that simply output to folder 'None'

Comment: if you are not updating your settings.py okay use this                                     def UploadedConfigPath(instance, filename):
       return os.path.join('uploadedconfigs/', str(instance.id), '/', filename)